# Unable to set an environment variable called token

Tags: macos, zsh

Running following version of `zsh` on Mac OS X.

```
zsh --version
zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin20.0)
```

Im trying to set an environment variable called `token` in interactive shell however Im unable to set this for some reason. Is this because it has a special meaning in zsh ?

```
token=test
```

and then `echo $token` produces `$token` instead of `test`.

however If I have,

```
TOKEN=test
```

then `echo $TOKEN` produces `test`.

Comment: You need to `export token`. That is, `export token; echo $token`

Comment: You dont necessarily need to do an `export` to set a variable.

Comment: You are probably setting environment variable in .bashrc file. So, whenever you open a new terminal, the contents of that file will be loaded and your environment will be set. Having an export inside .bashrc will make sure that your environment variable is accessible from every terminal. That's what I think happens.

Comment: Nope. not setting an environment variable in a bash file. This is in shell. Not in any child process either. So you don't even need to do an `export`.

Comment: This question should not be closed because its nothing to do with `export` as shown by the two examples.

Comment: You may try some different name for example `token2` instead of `token`.

Comment: Sure `token2` works fine. But my question is why `token` isnt working in bash ?

Comment: Can you try `echo "$token"` (with double quotes)?

Comment: It results in `"$token"`.

Comment: Seems like someone else is running into this very issue on `zsh`. https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/9918

Comment: Can you try using `typeset -p token` and check what it outputs? I get this output when I run `token=test; typeset -p token`  -> `declare -- token="test"`

Comment: `typeset -p token` produces `typeset token=token`. Possibly something in zsh/oh-my-zsh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232764/discussion-between-kiner-shah-and-nixgadget).

Comment: Are you sure your shell is actually bash and not zsh? bash follows POSIX guidelines that all-lowercase variable names should be safe for applications to use without having special meaning to the shell. zsh does not.

Comment: Mind, I wouldn't be surprised if you had a hook being run that reused the variable name but didn't declare its locals and so was polluting global namespace. If you run `set -x` and inspect the code being run between prompts that should be visible if it's the problem.

Comment: Do you still have the problem during script execution (as opposed to an interactive shell)? That would take a bunch of moving parts of of the picture.

Comment: @kiner_shah, it's definitely not caused by lack of `export`. The shell will automatically export updates to any previously exported variable (meaning everyone writing `export PATH=...` is doing so unnecessarily).

Comment: Seems it's only isolated to the interactive shell as far as i can tell.

Comment: Instead of `bash --version` (which shows us the version of bash first in your PATH), show output of `echo "$BASH_VERSION"`, which shows the actual running shell (which can be a different thing, and moreover will be empty if your active shell isn't actually bash).

Comment: @KamilCuk updated the question to zsh instead of bash

Comment: Ah. If it's zsh, this is utterly unsurprising -- because, as described above, zsh doesn't honor POSIX guidelines about all-lowercase variable namespace being reserved for application use. (It's possible to interpret the guidance in the standard as only being relevant to environment as opposed to shell variables, but as both types of variables use the same namespace, I consider that interpretation intentionally obtuse -- not to mention user-hostile for the reasons seen here).

Comment: Does `zsh -l -i -c 'token=test; echo $token'` reproduces?

Comment: `zsh -l -i -c 'token=test; echo $token'` produces `test`

Comment: Exact behaviour as described in https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/9918

Comment: Whatever the problem is, it's not purely with `zsh`. I installed 5.8 using `nix-shell -p zsh` on macOS 10.15, and cannot reproduce the output.

Comment: @nixgadget, does `set -x` show anything being assigned to `token`? How about checking the xtrace logs from `zsh -x -l -i` when run interactively?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy @chepner @KamilCuk thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Looking at the `ohmyzsh` code and `powerlevel10k` in particular it appears to be using it internally. https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/master/internal/parser.zsh

Comment: @nixgadget, adding a missing `local token` declaration in that powerlevel10k function may fix your issue.

Comment: Yup it does look like `powerlevel10k` has been patched to fix this now. Thanks for the help to track this down guys.